# php dom agregar un elemento

Tags: php, html, dom

Hola amigos me podrían ayudar con lo siguiente.

Tengo ese código HTML:

```
<figure class="class"><iframe src="src" width="xxx" height="xxx"></iframe></figure>
```

Pero quiero agregar un `iframe` mas para que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
<figure class="class"><iframe><iframe src="src" width="xxx" height="xxx"></iframe><iframe></figure>
```

Este es el código que estoy usando para envolverlo en esas etiquetas pero no puedo agregar el `iframe` que me falta.

```
$iframes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    foreach ($iframes as $iframeViejo) {
        //Crear un nuevo iframe y asignar el src
        $iframeMainn = $doc->createElement('iframe');
        $iframeNuevo->setAttribute('src', $iframeViejo->getAttribute('src'));
        $iframeNuevo->setAttribute('width','560');
        $iframeNuevo->setAttribute('height','615');
        //Crear un nuevo figure y agregarle el nuevo iframe
        $figureNuevo = $doc->createElement('figure');
        $figureNuevo->setAttribute('class','op-interactive');
        $figureNuevo->appendChild($iframeNuevo);
        //reemplazar viejo por nuevo
        $iframeViejo->parentNode->replaceChild($figureNuevo, $iframeViejo);
    }
```

Me podrían ayudar por favor,

saludos

Comment: creo que no deberia estar en el for

Comment: El código que compartes no agrega un nuevo `iframe` sino un nuevo `figure`

Answer (score 1):

El código que compartes:

- Tiene un error con los nombres de las variables: se crea una variable `iframeMainn` que luego no se usa, y se intenta utilizar `iframeNuevo` sin haberlo inicializado. Supongo que realmente donde pone `iframeMainn` debería poner `iframeNuevo`.
- En lugar de agregar un nuevo `iframe` agrega un nuevo `figure`: por lo que el resultado será `figure > figure > iframe` en lugar de `figure > iframe > iframe`.
- Usa [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/es/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php). Esto no es un problema en sí, pero es importante recordar que ese método devuelve una lista dinámica, es decir, si añades otro `iframe` al DOM dentro de tu bucle `foreach`, se añadirá un nuevo elemento a la lista y acabarás dentro de un bucle infinito.

Teniendo eso en cuenta e intentando cambiar lo mínimo posible el código que compartes, te sugeriría que hicieses los siguientes cambios:

1. Cambiar `iframeMainn` por `iframeNuevo`:

   ```
   $iframeNuevo = $doc->createElement('iframe');
   ```
2. Agregar un `iframe` en lugar de un `figure`:

   ```
   $figureNuevo = $doc->createElement('iframe');
   ```
3. Ahora que estás agregando un nuevo `iframe` tendrías el problema del bucle infinito que comento arriba; para evitarlo, vuelva los datos del `getElementsByTagName` a un array normal y luego atraviesa ese array. El nuevo array será "estático" ya que sólo contendrá los elementos originales del `getElementsByTagName`:

   ```
   $iframes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
   $arrayiframes = array();
   foreach ($iframes as $iframeViejo) {
       $arrayiframes[] = $iframeViejo;
   }

   foreach($arrayiframes as $iframeViejo) {
       ....
   ```

Con esos cambios el código quedaría así:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML("<figure class='class'><iframe src='src' width='300' height='200'></iframe></figure>");

$iframes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
$arrayiframes = array();
foreach ($iframes as $iframeViejo) {
    $arrayiframes[] = $iframeViejo;
}

foreach($arrayiframes as $iframeViejo) {
    //Crear un nuevo iframe y asignar el src
    $iframeNuevo = $doc->createElement('iframe');
    $iframeNuevo->setAttribute('src', $iframeViejo->getAttribute('src'));
    $iframeNuevo->setAttribute('width','560');
    $iframeNuevo->setAttribute('height','615');
    //Crear un nuevo figure y agregarle el nuevo iframe
    $figureNuevo = $doc->createElement('iframe');
    $figureNuevo->appendChild($iframeNuevo);
    //reemplazar viejo por nuevo
    $iframeViejo->parentNode->replaceChild($figureNuevo, $iframeViejo);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Con el que se obtiene el resultado esperado:

```
<figure class="class"><iframe><iframe src="src" width="560" height="615"></iframe></iframe></figure>
```

Nota: para ver el resultado debes ver el código fuente y no inspeccionar el código. Esto se debe a cómo los navegadores representan los `iframe`s (lo que hay entre los tags `<iframe></iframe>` sólo se mostrará si el navegador no soporta `iframe`.